# How to plot a rolling window of five points from a matrix using animate in Maple

Tags: maple

This question is about animating a plot of 3d points in Maple.

Consider the parametric function

$$f(t)=(0,\cos{t},\sin{t})$$

Let's create a matrix of twenty points of this function, each row being a point.

```
pd := Matrix([seq(f(t), t = 0 .. 20)]);
```

We can plot these points

```
pointplot3d(pd)
```

to obtain

[image]

Now, imagine we want to have an animation that plots a rolling window of five points. That is, first we plot rows 1-5, then rows 2-6, then 3-7, and so on.

I thought about implementing this as follows

```
with(plots):
animate(pointplot3d, [pd[t .. t + 5, () .. ()]], t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

However, I get an error

> Error, non-integer ranges in Matrix index

The indexing of the matrix is being done using values of $t$ from $1$ to $5$, if I understand correctly.

Here is a similar example that also uses a list for this same parameter to animate

```
animate(plot3d, [[sin(q^2 + q)*cos(q), sin(q^2 + q)*sin(q), cos(q^2 + q)], q = s - 1 .. s], s = [seq(i, i = 1 .. 5)], frames = 100)
```

This produces the correct animation.

I would like to attach my worksheet, but I can't see how.

In any case, why does the first use of animate not work?

EDIT: the following workaround seems to work

```
m1 := proc(pd, t) 
  return pointplot3d(pd[t .. t + 5, () .. ()]); 
end proc

animate(m1, [pd, t], t = [seq(i, i = 1 .. 15)])
```

What I am doing with this code is passing my own function as the first parameter to `pointplot3d`. The docs say this first parameter is a

> Maple procedure that generates a 2-D or 3-D plot or plot objects

I wasn't sure if this would work because when I check the return value of `pointplot3d` it is a function. I am not sure how the type system is in Maple. But this did work. And when I print out the value of `t` in the function `m1` they seem to be integers.

Not sure why the original (easier) way isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a common mistake and encountering what is sometimes known in Maple as *premature evaluation*.

The usual mechanism for how Maple handles procedure calls is that the arguments are evaluated *up front*, and then passed into the procedure.

You are passing the following as the second argument to the `animate` command, and it emits an error because at this moment (prior to entering the animate procedure itself) there is no value of `t`. And the Matrix `pd` cannot be indexed in such an indeterminate way.

```
pd[t .. t + 25, ..];
Error, non-integer ranges in Matrix index
```

There are several ways to accomplish what you're after.

One way is to *delay* the evaluation of `pointplot3d` by using a so-called operator calling sequence of `animate`, with another procedure, as in your second example.

Another way is *delay* the evaluation with single right-ticks (aka *uneval quotes* in Maple).

For example (using a slightly larger number of points, for fun):

```
restart;
with(plots):
f := t -> [0,cos(t),sin(t)]:
pd := Matrix([seq(f(t), t=0..50)]):

pointplot3d(pd);

animate(pointplot3d,
        ['pd[t .. t + 25, ..]'],
        t = [$1..25]);
```

There are other ways, including construction of the individual frames using `seq`, which has [special evaluation rules](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=spec_eval_rules).